# Enchantment tags not working

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to do this command:

```
/give @p Minecraft:diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {[id:34,lvl:30000]},{[id:32,lvl:30000]},{[id:70,lvl:30000]},{[id:35,lvl:30000]},{[id:16,lvl:500]}
```

But it says *data tag parsing failed: encountered multiple top tags*. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Currently each of your compound tags - `{}` - is a separate top tag, when you should only have one. Let's put all of your current compound tags into a single compound tag so that there's only one top tag:

```
/give @p diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {{[id:34,lvl:30000]},{[id:32,lvl:30000]},{[id:70,lvl:30000]},{[id:35,lvl:30000]},{[id:16,lvl:500]}}
```

This command isn't fixed yet though. Each enchantment compound tag should be inside a list - `[]` - called `ench`:

```
/give @p diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {ench:[{[id:34,lvl:30000]},{[id:32,lvl:30000]},{[id:70,lvl:30000]},{[id:35,lvl:30000]},{[id:16,lvl:500]}]}
```

Finally, each enchantment compound tag (e.g: `{[id:34,lvl:30000]}`) should contain `id` and `lvl` directly, rather than contain a list containing `id` and `lvl`. This is the fixed command:

```
/give @p diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {ench:[{id:34,lvl:30000},{id:32,lvl:30000},{id:70,lvl:30000},{id:35,lvl:30000},{id:16,lvl:500}]}
```

You'll also probably crash your game if you mine something like lapis with this pick, so you should probably decrease the `lvl` to 10 or so for fortune.

---

I'd recommend using [a generator](https://ezekielelin.com/give/), or reading a guide on data tags.

Comment: i found something on youtube and it chashed my game when i opened my inventory

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the enchantments in an `ench` tag. Here's the command for that:

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {ench:[{id:34,lvl:30000},{id:32,lvl:30000},{id:70,lvl:30000},{id:35,lvl:30000},{id:16,lvl:500}]}
```

Also, I believe that using such high enchantment levels will lag the game. You may want to consider lowering them (for me, the most I can have is level 200).

Hope this helps!